# Precompile Azure WebRole on Visual Studio 2012 publish (Not through WebDeploy)

Tags: asp.net, azure

I am trying to precompile my WebForms (WebRole) application before publishing it to Azure from Visual Studio 2012. There are multiple instances so WebDeploy is not an option.

I havent found any "best practices" to that yet.
Any ideas about how to accomplish that?

EDIT:
Is there any way to preload all pages at startup so that the users dosent need to take the compilation hit for the first page load/compile for all pages?
All pages except the login page is behind Form Authentication in my case. Any ideas?

Comment: No simple way but maybe if more people voted here MS will add it sooner: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169386-cloud-services-web-and-worker-role/suggestions/5863196-allow-easy-asp-net-precompilation-in-cloud-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is kind of tricky however you can do it in stage. First you create a precompiled web-site and then add Azure specific configuration ServiceDefiniton.csdef by adding proper setting. Next use CSPACK.EXE to package the web-site into cspkg and you will get ServiceConfiguration.cscfg as well. Now you can do offline deployment to Windows Azure cloud service.

Check out this posting for step by step details: [Website Projects in Azure Web Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098988/website-projects-in-azure-web-role)

Comment: Thanks! Are there any reason why its not as easy as just checking an box. Is there any other reason why precompilation is not desiarable in a WebRole?

The major issue for me is that I have an application with many complex pages and the first page hit (not site) is taking ~20-30 seconds which is not acceptable.
Is there any other solution that you would recommend?